# Django 1.5 Custom User for m2m field 'groups' clashes

Tags: python, django, django-models

Have I done this right? I have created a **custom user in Django 1.5** which works. I now want to add a completely different type of user to the mix called `WebUser` allowing very simple access to front-end pages/ public users who have signed-up. However, every time I try I get the following error...

**Try to add this:**

```
class WebUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'accounts'
```

**I get this:**

> accounts.companyuser: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with
>   related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'groups'. accounts.companyuser: Accessor for m2m field
>   'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field
>   'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition
>   for 'user_permissions'. accounts.participantuser: Accessor for m2m
>   field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a
>   related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
>   accounts.participantuser: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions'
>   clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a
>   related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.

**This is my full model working version before I tried to add the new user:**

```
class EmailUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves an EmailUser with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = EmailUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=False, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=False, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class AbstractEmailUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Abstract User with the same behaviour as Django's default User but
    without a username field. Uses email as the USERNAME_FIELD for
    authentication.

    Use this if you need to extend EmailUser.

    Inherits from both the AbstractBaseUser and PermissionMixin.

    The following attributes are inherited from the superclasses:
        * password
        * last_login
        * is_superuser
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255,
                              unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = EmailUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the email.
        """
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        """
        Returns the email.
        """
        return self.email

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])


class CompanyUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    """
    Concrete class of AbstractEmailUser.

    """

    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
```

Comment: Don't think you can have multiple custom `User` models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs for [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)

> If you are using the related_name attribute on a ForeignKey or
>   ManyToManyField, you must always specify a unique reverse name for the
>   field. This would normally cause a problem in abstract base classes,
>   since the fields on this class are included into each of the child
>   classes, with exactly the same values for the attributes (including
>   related_name) each time.

And look at [`PermissionMixin` code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a9093dd3763df6b2045a08b0520f248bda708723/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L278).

One way that I see is to replace `PermissionMixin` with your own class but it may break a lot more because related names will change.

Comment: I see thanks. right, back to the drawing board then. I kinda what my users to have their own users and this will not work. I only want one customer user model but the web user is under the main user i.e. their users if that makes any sense at all